# Angular Draggable under ng-template with TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap, draggable

Apologies if it's been asked before, I haven't been able to find anything hence asking around if anyone could be of assistance. So I am working on creating a Bootstrap Modal popup with form in it and I want it to be **Draggable**, for this purpose I've used a simple button, on clicking the button I display **ng-template**, I am unable to drag the contents of it if I use angular2-draggable, if I take out the ng-template and simple use a Div, it works fine.
Is there a way I could make Angular Draggable work under ng-template. Some basic code extract is as follows,

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="open(testDialog)">TestDrag</button>

<ng-template #testDialog let-modal>
  <div ngDraggable>
    <div
      class="
        modal-header
        row
        d-flex
        justify-content-between
        mx-1 mx-sm-3
        mb-0
        pb-0
        border-0
      "
    >
      <h3 class="modal-title">Asset</h3>
      This is the header
      <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">This is the body</div>
    <div class="modal-footer">This is the footer</div>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

If I remove the ng-template and just print a normal div, dragging works perfect.
Can anyone please help how I can use it under ng-template.

**EDIT:** Here is the open method that is under irgraph.component.ts file,

```
open(content: any) {
        this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title', centered: true}).result.then((result) => {
            this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
        }, (reason) => {
            this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${IRGraphComponent.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
        });
    }
```

Comment: why must you use ng-template. Why not just use the div?

Comment: What does the open function look like?

Comment: @E.Maggini - Actually new to the whole Bootstrap, Angular and Typescripting, so followed tutorial at https://remotestack.io/angular-bootstrap-modal-popup-tutorial-example/ and found it working so used it ... now as I'm long way into development, find it hard to revert to Div ... hence trying to find a solution that I could do within ng-templates

Comment: @MikeOne - the open method looks like what I've just added to my question above, under EDIT section ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @E.Maggini, I switched from ng-template to Div and then it seems to work without any issues. Followed the guidelines from [Angular 2 Draggable](https://xieziyu.github.io/angular2-draggable/#/home)